# How do I display the shells used on my Unix machine?

Tags: macos, shell, unix, command

Is there a Unix command I can use to display all the shells present on my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would do:

`cat /etc/shells`

To see what is considered an "approved" shell on your system.

Then verify that the files listed in /etc/shells are actually present (e.g. `ls /bin/bash`).

If they are, you can use the `chsh` command to change your shell to one of the listed shells.

There isn't any specific command I'm aware of to list installed shells, but the process I just described should get you there.